# Detect a key press and show it in a label tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pynput

Im using tkinter and pynput. I have a button to select a trigger key after the user press the key I want to show the ord of the pressed key in a label this is the error: `ord() expected string of length 1, but KeyCode found`
and here is the code:

```
TriggerKey = Button(win, text = "Set a trigger key", command = Key_listener)
TriggerKey.place(x = 70, y = 70,)
```

This is the Listen function:

```
def Key_listener():
    with Listener (on_press=trigger_Key, on_release=release) as trigger:
        trigger.join()
```

and here is where I think the problem is:

```
def trigger_Key(Key):
    TriggerKey = Key
    print(TriggerKey) #prints the pressed button for a test
    ord_key = ord(TriggerKey)
    trigger_key_label.config(text= ord_key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used it with `tkinter`,it will block your code.
Change your function `Key_listener`:

```
def Key_listener():
    trigger = Listener (on_press=trigger_Key, on_release=release)
    trigger.start()
```

---

About your error:
in the `trigger_Key`,key is a `Keycode` function.You need to use `ord(Key.char)`.

Comment: How can I make this work with CTRL button as well? when I try press CTRL this is the error I get: 'Key' object has no attribute 'char'

Comment: @yair Use a if statement to judge it,or use `try...except....` to catch the error.